# Update CSV file in foreach loop

Tags: powershell, csv, variables, foreach

I have a `foreach` loop in PowerShell. It runs through some users moving data based on a CSV file.
I would like to update the CSV file for each line that has bee ran, so a CSV looking like this:

```
Username;OldData;NewData;Status
User1;c:\Old;c:\new;Waiting
User2;d:\Old;D:\New;Waiting
```

Will as the last line in the first `foreach` loop (assuming the data has been copied) change the CSV to:

```
Username;OldData;NewData;Status
User1;c:\Old;c:\new;Done
User2;d:\Old;D:\New;Waiting
```

And again after User2 has finished update it to:

```
Username;OldData;NewData;Status    
User1;c:\Old;c:\new;Done
User2;d:\Old;D:\New;Done
```

What I do now is import the CSV with

```
$Table = Import-Csv c:\csv.csv
```

and then run the `foreach` (pseudo code)

```
foreach ($Row in $Table) {
    Copy-Content $row.OldData $row.NewData
    Update-Csv $row.Status = "Done"
}
```

Comment: Remove `Update-Csv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After following [@AnsgarWiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56495983/update-csv-file-in-foreach-loop#comment99581235_56495983) hint, save changed $Table with

```
$Table | Export-Csv C:\csv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

To avoid processing the same line multiple times on successive runs, exclude the ones with Status `Done`

```
## Q:\Test\2019\06\07\SO_56495983.ps1

$File = '.\csv.csv' # 'c:\csv.csv'  #
$Table = Import-Csv $File -Delimiter ';'

foreach ($Row in ($Table|Where Status -eq 'Waiting')) {
    #Copy-Content $row.OldData $row.NewData
    $row.Status = "Done"
}

$Table
$Table | Export-Csv $File  -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: So it won't mess up the to loop changing the active table it is running after? - doing the ´$row.Status = "Done"´

Comment: I had overlooked the missing `-Delimiter ';'`. Should work now as expected.